# Send a zip file as a response using python

Tags: python, django, zip, response

I am given a zip file that I need to send to UI from where it should be downloaded for the user.
While testing on POSTMAN, using Send & Download button associated with POST, I am able to download the file. But when opening it, it says:

> Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed(zipped) folder <zip path> is invalid

Here's the code I am trying:

```
from django.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

def get_response():
    with open(zip_file_path.zip, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
        file_data = f.read()
        response = Response(file_data, content_type='application/zip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ReportTest.zip"'
    return response

class GenerateZIP(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        zip_file_response = get_response()
        return zip_file_response
```

The zip file read is valid as it's already on the local.
Any ideas?

Comment: isn't it just because you open your file in text mode and not binary mode ?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: @viper no, when I do with binary it raises 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a

Comment: well yes, because in binary mode you shouldn't give any encoding

Comment: @IainShelvington its 3.2.7

Comment: @Viper yes, but that doesn't resolves the issue. Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than generate the response yourself, you can use a [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) which does it for you

```
from django.http import FileResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class GenerateZIP(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        return FileResponse(
            open('zip_file_path.zip', 'rb'),
            as_attachment=True,
            filename='ReportTest.zip'
        )
```

Comment: Idk how but this does work for me. Thank you @IainShelvington